# Android get value of checkbox from listview

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have this code that I need to delete datas that are checked within the listview but my problem is that I only get the first checkbox. when I checked the second checkbox it does not retrieved the data. Also the getChildCount() returns 0 why is it like that? I dont know how will I progress with my problem. Thank you.

here is my code:

```
btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RetailerDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new RetailerDatabaseHelper(TemplateActivity.this);
            final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); //For further investigation!

            Cursor c10 = db.query("Retailer", new String[]{"_id", "name", "validity"}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(TemplateActivity.this, R.layout.custom_dialog_box, c10, new String[]{"name", "validity"}, new int[]{R.id.checkBox1, R.id.number}, 0);
            ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);

            Log.d("Inside Button", "Test Child: " + myList.getChildCount() + " Adapter: " + adapter.getCount() + " getAdapter: " + myList.getAdapter().getCount() + " Child: " + myList.getChildAt(1));

            for(int x = 0; x < myList.getAdapter().getCount(); x++)
            {
                View nextChild = myList.getChildAt(x);
                if(nextChild instanceof CheckBox)
                {
                    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)nextChild;
                    if(checkbox.isChecked())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would preface this by saying: never do database work on the UI/main thread in Android. It will block the UI and lead to your application freezing. Check out the "Threads" section of [this resource for more info](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

To solve your current problem, you may want to maintain a list of "checked" items. This will likely involve maintaining a list of ids that have been populated using [a listener on your check boxes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) that you can set in your list's adapter view binding code. On the check changed you can then add the id to your list, and upon deletion you can tell your database which ids need to be deleted. For this solution, you will likely want to investigate making your own adapter. The simple cursor adapter will not get you very far ;)

Also, you may want to check out RecyclerView -- the newer version of ListView.

Comment: oooh. sorry i'm new in android programming thats why i dont know my way around.

Answer (score 0):

@Kathleen51
i  use SparseBooleanArray  in BaseAdapter. edit your code like this...

```
class OutPatientServiceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<OutPatientService> beans;
    private viewHolder holder;
    private Context c;
    private SparseBooleanArray booleanArray;

    public OutPatientServiceAdapter(Context c,
            ArrayList<OutPatientService> beans) {
        super();
        this.c = c;
        this.beans = beans;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        booleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray(beans.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < beans.size(); i++) {
            booleanArray.put(i, true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return beans.size();
    }

    @Override
    public OutPatientService  getItem(int position) {
        return beans.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        holder = new viewHolder();
        final OutPatientService bean = (OutPatientService) getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.outpatient_service_item, parent, false);
            holder.itemText = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.itemText);
            holder.doctorText = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.doctorText);
            holder.priceText = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.priceText);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        boolean check = booleanArray.get(position);
        holder.itemText.setChecked(check);
        holder.itemText
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        booleanArray.put(position, isChecked);
                    }
                });
        holder.itemText.setText(bean.recipe_name);
        holder.doctorText.setText(bean.create_doctor);
        holder.priceText.setText(bean.fee);
        return convertView;
    }

    public class viewHolder {
        public CheckBox itemText;
        public TextView doctorText;
        public TextView priceText;
    }

    public SparseBooleanArray getmSpCheckedState() {
        return booleanArray;
    }

    public void selectAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < beans.size(); i++) {
            if (!booleanArray.get(i)) {
                booleanArray.put(i, true);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < beans.size(); i++) {
            if (booleanArray.get(i)) {
                booleanArray.put(i, false);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, what if the datas are coming from the database?

Comment: Don't  use SimpleCursorAdapter.you can create custom object contain  id,name,validity. then  transform  db.query   to ArrayList<custom object>.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853531/read-from-a-database-in-android-to-an-arraylist

Comment: can you give me a headstart on what should i do with the custom object?

Comment: creat  a  class.                                                                                         public class OutPatientService {
  public int id;
  public String name;
  public String validity;
 }